# Have the code written but need to use either a while or for loop

Tags: python

my program `askTheUser()` works the way I want it too but I'm somehow supposed to change it to include either a "for" or "while" loop. Any suggestions? The ending result is supposed to be a list of zeros and ones. For example, [1,1,1,1,1] would mean they would like to re-roll every dice.

```
import random
def askTheUser():
    userList = []
    choice = input("Would you like to re-roll dice 1? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.")
    if choice == str("Yes"):
        userList.append(1)
    else:
        userList.append(0)
    choice2 = input("Would you like to re-roll dice 2? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.")
    if choice2 == str("Yes"):
        userList.append(1)
    else:
        userList.append(0)
    choice3 = input("Would you like to re-roll dice 3? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.")
    if choice3 == str("Yes"):
        userList.append(1)
    else:
        userList.append(0)    
    choice4 = input("Would you like to re-roll dice 4? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.")
    if choice4 == str("Yes"):
        userList.append(1)
    else:
        userList.append(0)    
    choice5 = input("Would you like to re-roll dice 5? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.")
    if choice5 == str("Yes"):
        userList.append(1)
    else:
        userList.append(0)   
    return userList
```

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you realize that you are writing the same code over and over again, you should think about how to automate that. In your case, the only thing that actually changes in your 5 parts is the dice number in the text, and the variable the result is being assigned to.

So the first step would be to make the input text accept a variable dice number. We can use string formatting for that:

```
"Would you like to re-roll dice {}? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.".format(i)
```

Now the value of `i` will be inserted in the place of `{}` in the string.

Next, we should think about those `choice` variables. If you think about it, we don’t actually need separate ones for what they do. After all, they only capture the user input, and immediately after we evaluate the value and then forget about them. So we can just name them all `choice` overwriting the input each time.

So for dice number `i`, we have this as the relevant code (also note that `str("something")` is equivalent to just `"something"`):

```
choice = input("Would you like to re-roll dice {}? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.".format(i))
if choice == "Yes":
    userList.append(1)
else:
    userList.append(0)
```

The only thing that changes now is the value of `i`, which should go from `1` to `5`. So we use a loop for that, and that’s all:

```
def askTheUser():
    userList = []
    for i in range(1, 6):
        choice = input("Would you like to re-roll dice {}? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'.".format(i))
        if choice == "Yes":
            userList.append(1)
        else:
            userList.append(0)
    return userList
```

Btw. as you are collecting “decisions” whether or not to reroll individual dice, it would actually make more sense to store boolean values `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`. So you would append `True` or `False` instead:

```
if choice == "Yes":
    userList.append(True)
else:
    userList.append(False)
```

And in that case, you can then just append the result from the comparison directly instead:

```
userList.append(choice == "Yes")
```

And then, when you later check the values, instead of having to check `if decision == 1`, you can just do `if decision`.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining everything as you did it. Really appreciate it. It certainly helps for such a beginner coder like myself!

Comment: I figured that a more detailed explanation might help—glad it did, you’re welcome :) Btw. please remember to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it solved your question to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
def askTheUser():
    userList = []
    for i in range(5):
        choice = raw_input("Would you like to re-roll dice "+str(i)+"? If so, enter 'Yes'.   If not, enter 'No'.")
        if choice == str("Yes"):
            userList.append(1)

        else:
            userList.append(0)

    return userList
```

Please check this!!

Comment: I don't think the `break` or `continue` statements are needed. `continue` is simply unnecessary, while `break` makes the code behave differently than the unrolled original.

Comment: if the option is 'no', then there is no use of going for next loop na>??

Comment: The code is only meant to ask whether or not to reroll each die though. I guess you can re-roll die 4 without having to re-roll dice 1–3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def askTheUser():
    userList=[]
    for i in range(5):
        choice = input("Would you like to re-roll dice %d? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'."%(i+1))
        userList.append(1 if choice == 'Yes' else 0)
    return userList
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
def askTheUser():
    userList = []
    for i in range(1,6):
        question = "Would you like to re-roll dice " + str(i) + "? If so, enter 'Yes'. If not, enter 'No'."
        choice = input(question)
        if choice == str("Yes"):
            userList.append(1)
        else:
            userList.append(0)
    return userList
```

Comment: For some reason, It only asks if you would like to re-roll dice 5. And when I answer it only gives me either a [0] or [1] instead of [1,1,0,1,0]

Comment: @user3367018 Are you running Python 2 or 3?